# Minimizing steps to distribute in a candies in a circle

Tags: algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory

There are `n` children in a circle. Each of them has some candies (may be negative, positive or zero). They can give at a time a single candy to their neighbors. The end result is that they all should have zero candies in minimum steps.

Suppose we have 4 children with `(-4, -2, 4, 2)` candies then the sequence will be

1. (-3, -2, 4, 1)
2. (-2, -2, 4, 0)
3. (-2, -1, 3, 0)
4. (-2,  0, 2, 0)
5. (-2,  1, 1, 0)
6. (-2,  2, 0, 0)
7. (-1,  1, 0, 0)
8. ( 0,  0, 0, 0)

This is one possible answer, I have to find minimum number of steps.

- Loop 1: find if a neighbor has positive candies,then give it to the neighbor with negative candies till number of candies is equal to zero and add the number of candies given to sum.
- Loop 2: find if a  neighbors' neighbour has positive candies, then give it to the neighbor with negative candies till number of candies is equal to zero and add 2 (the number of candies given to sum).
- and so on.

The complexity of my solution is causing a TLE. What can I do to reduce the complexity?

Comment: Try referencing to the online judge you are using

Comment: max value of n is 10000 and time limit is 3 seconds. this was in my college coding comp on interviewstreet. I was not able to solve it but was curious to know what is the answer.

Comment: Negative candy? Those poor kids!

Comment: TLE = "Temporal lobe epilepsy"?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you need to loop round in detail. Write the number of candies in each place as X1, X2, X3, X4. Suppose that X1 receives k candies from its left (that is, for X4). After this it has X1+k candies, so it must pass this to its right. Then X2 will have X1 + X2 + k candies, so it must pass this to its right. X3 will then have X1 + X2 + X3 + k candies, so it must pass this to X4. We know X4 passed k candies, and this checks (assuming that X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 = 0 and if it doesn't there is no solution).

This takes |k| + |X1 + k| + |X1 + X2 + k| + |X1 + X2 + X3 + k| steps, so if we guess k we know how many steps to take. What is the best value of k? If we increase k we increase the sum if there are more +ve terms X1 + X2 + ... k, and decrease if there are more -ve terms. So the best value of k is one in which exactly half of the terms |k|, |X1 + k|.. are +ve and exactly half -ve because if this is not the case we can either increase or decrease k to make things better - the value of k to choose is - the median of 0, X1, X1 + X2, X1 + X2 + X3.

I have stated this for the n=4 case of your example but I hope that you can work out the answer for general n from this.

Comment: Arrgh! I had solved this 15 min back (with the exact same approach) and could only log in now. +1. Well done :-)

Comment: It clicked after I realised that k could be negative, representing a transfer from right to left.  Then if we assume we know how many candies were transferred to kid i from the kid on their left, this and the number of candies kid i started with determines how many candies they must pass to the kid on their right in order to wind up with 0 for themselves.  We could in theory guess k to be greater than the sum of all positive candy counts (causing candies to "pop into existence"), but such trial solutions will never be chosen because they can't be optimal.  Nice!

Comment: Awesome solution @angelatlarge explanation was needed.

Answer (score 4):

Taking **mcdowella**'s idea, and putting it into my words (because it took me a while to understand it, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174313/create-a-new-answer-or-edit-an-existing-answer-if-the-existing-answer-could-be-c) for some handwringing on this topic) makes it look as follows.  The key insights are:

- Just like you can own negative candy, you can pass negative candy as well
- Passing negative candy in one direction is basically passing (positive) candy in the opposite direction
- Whatever the amound of candy a child has, everyone is going to end up at zero.

This implement this as follows: pick an arbitrary child to start with (Child A in the following diagram, where I have 5 children instead of 4), and we pick an arbitrary direction (counterclockwise, in our case), and start passing. Every child has to get rid of all its candy (positive or negative) to get to zero.  So child A has `-2` candy so we pass that to Child B. After that child B has -5 candy so we pass that to child C. Now child C has -4 candy, and passes that to D, and so on. This is the second diagram and all the candies are at zero in 13 moves.

[image]

The senter diagram is not optimal. We observe that all the candy that's passed in the center diagram is negative (save the E->A pass) and that **we can add or subtract from first pass at will**: if A->B pass was `+5` instead of `-2`, then all the passes would be incremented by `7`, and E->A pass would have been `7` instead of 0, and in the end A would still have no candy.  So we seek a number by which we can adjust all passes such that the sum of absolute values of all passes is minimized. In the last diagram we see that if we add `+2` to all passes, the sum of absolute values of all passes is 7. As an illustration, if we added `+3` the sum would have been larger. So we seek to add a constant to all passes that minimizes the sum of absolute value of all passes.

P.S. If someone thinks my re-telling of **mcdowella**'s idea should not be here, I will be happy to delete.

Comment: It's a good explanation :) I took a while to click to the "negative k == candies being passed in the reverse direction" idea in mcdowella's answer too.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I just wasn't sure whether to post this or not: I didn't want to steal mcdowella's intellectual credit, but I thought the idea was neat, and maybe there was another way of explaining it.

Comment: You clearly gave him/her credit right at the outset -- that's all anyone needs to do I reckon! More explanations == good :)

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 1):

One meta-approach that applies here is to take an algorithm that polls and make it event-based. What do I mean?

Maintain a circularly linked list containing the givers (children with >0 candies) and takers (children with <0 candies). Maintain also a priority queue that contains an entry for each adjacent (in the list, not in the circle) giver-taker pair whose key is the distance between the giver and the taker.

Now, instead of incrementing the distance one at a time, use the priority queue to figure out the next interesting thing that happens. Every time a giver-taker pair is resolved, one or both children drop out of the list, which necessitates O(1) bookkeeping and queue insertions.